# How bypass long path names during copy from hard drive to external hard drive

Tags: windows-7, filenames

I have a big problem during copy files from my hard drive to external hard drive.
During copy i saw 10-40 errors related to long path names and i skipped all of them.
Unfortunately windows 7 do n't show those paths completely to find those files and fix their name manually.

My questions :

1. Is there any third party app to recognize long path names & let me rename those files again?
2. Please give me a good solution for bypass long path names during copy.
3. I tried `robocopy` for copy files - But it is very very slow.(2 TB data) - Any idea?

**EDIT**
My both hard drive formats are NTFS.

Comment: Not positive on W7, but you cloud try enable Long File Paths just modify the value to be 1 under  HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem

Comment: @SQLTemp Which REG_DWORD value should i change in that path? (There is no Long File Paths there)

Comment: on W10 it’s LongPathsEnabled

Comment: Total Commander solved this issue. Speed of TC is very good. During copy it will ask for copy long path names & you can choose do it.

Comment: @SQLTemp This trick only works on windows 10, Not windows 7.

Comment: I also tired 7 Zip File Manager. It is useless and has problem with some file names.